# Trying to build a web page that can generate an image

Tags: javascript, php, html, image-processing, web-applications

I've been having trouble getting started with this project because I'm not sure what I should be searching for. Any help on where/how to start would be greatly appreciated.

The idea is, I have an image of a postcard that I want users to be able to upload and add their logo to a designated blank area and then download it. Hopefully all through a single web page.

If it can be all be done locally through their browser without actually uploading anything to my web server, even better!

So, I'm trying to figure out what I should use to accomplish this.

Thank you again in advance for any suggestions and help!

Comment: [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/) might be helpful

Answer (score -1):

To get you started, have a look at PHP and [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org). What you want to do is called to *composite* two images. You can read in great detail how to use imagemagick to composite two images here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/

In PHP, you can use the [`Imagick::compositeImage`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php) method. Start there and let me know how you get on.